# CodeIgniter calendar date display - showing one day early in production

Tags: linux, codeigniter, ubuntu, time, calendar

I'm using the CodeIgniter calendar class to generate an availability calendar.  I use a loop to check if a date is in the "reserved" array, and if it is, give that cell a class of booked.

For some reason, on my server (Ubuntu 11.04), when the calendar is displayed the booked dates are showing one day earlier than they should.  I'm trying to debug this, as the problem does not appear on my local machine and the values in the database are correct.  Since it works on my local machine, I think it shouldn't be a code problem, either.

I've verified that the php.ini settings for date.timezone are identical, and the system dates (when you type 'date' in command line) are also identical.

Can anyone give me further insight into how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out where my issue was.  The timezone on my database server was incorrect (6 hours behind my production server).